# useLocation() error appears when requireAuth is used

Tags: reactjs, react-router, authkit

I am using react router with react-auth-kit, now in my app.js

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { RequireAuth } from "react-auth-kit";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
      <Route
        exact
        path="*"
        element={
          <RequireAuth loginPath="/log-in">
            <Home />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
      <Route path="/log-in" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see I am using RequireAuth to like require authentication in my app before accessing the Home Links.

This is my Home.jsx

```
import Nav from "../components/Nav";
import AddPr from "../components/Add_PR";
import GetPr from "../components/Get_PR";
import PRDetails from "../components/Pr_Details";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div className="">
      <Nav />
      <div className="w-full pt-10 p-16 h-screen">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<GetPr />} />
          <Route path="/pr-add" element={<AddPr />} />
          <Route path="/pr-details/:id" element={<PRDetails />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

But why am I getting this error:

```
useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

I can't seem to find any solution to my problem, I already wrapped my App with BrowserRouter.

```
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { RequireAuth } from "react-auth-kit";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();
  return (
    <Routes location={location} key={location.pathname}>
      <Route
        exact
        path="*"
        element={
          <RequireAuth loginPath="/log-in">
            <Home />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
      <Route path="/log-in" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And one thing I noticed is that the error only occurs when I added the RequireAuth tag here

```
 <Route
        exact
        path="*"
        element={
          <RequireAuth loginPath="/log-in">
            <Home />
          </RequireAuth>
        }
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your `App` component is wrapped inside a `BrowserRouter` in the index/main js file.

```
const Main = (
      <BrowserRouter>
          <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
);
```

And only then inside the `App` component you can use the brouter specifics.

Comment: I aready wrapped the App with a BrowserRouter. One thing I noticed is that the error occurs when I added the RequireAuth tag